# I'm desperate and need help with MFRC522 (stops working randomly)

Tags: relay, rfid

I've made a light switcher that switches lights on for 15s after a correct tag is presented, and also when door is opened for 6 seconds (its for outside) so i can see a keyhole after leaving for a brief amount of time. It works perfectly, but the rfid reader stops reading tags after random amounts of time (sometimes after hour and sometimes after days) - I've tried i think everything in terms of software (except watchdog) and i simply ran out of ideas. I need it to work, so i draw all the connections in the picture below - if anyone got any ideas, please let me now.

*Side note - everything is mounted and hidden outside so each even smallest hardware change is very hard to do so please, don't throw random ideas in this matter even tho **every** help is appreciated*

[image: scheme]

EDIT: I made a photo of interior of the enclosure that holds relay, arduino and charger PCB and decided to add it here too

[image]

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

//blue
const byte UID1[] = {0xA7, 0x8C, 0x24, 0xD9};
//blacks
const byte UID2[] = {0x10, 0x84, 0xD2, 0x2A};
const byte UID3[] = {0xDC, 0x46, 0xB6, 0x91};
const byte UID4[] = {0xB0, 0xE8, 0xC4, 0x2A};
//reds
const byte UID5[] = {0x9E, 0xC8, 0xEA, 0xB3};
const byte UID6[] = {0xFE, 0xA5, 0xF7, 0xB3};
//const byte UID6[] = {0x70, 0xBA, 0x35, 0xA5};

#define RST_PIN 9
#define SS_PIN 10

MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);
MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;
int in1 = 7;
int dooropen = 8;
int state = 0;
int testerbester = 0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();
  rfid.PCD_Init();
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dooropen, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {
  delay(200);
  state = digitalRead(dooropen);
  if (state == HIGH) {
    //Serial.println("Door Opened");
    testerbester = 1;
    digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
  } else {
    if (testerbester == 1) {
      delay(6000);
      testerbester = 0;
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    } else {
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    }
    if ( ! rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
    {
      return;
    }
    if ( ! rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
    {
      return;
    }
    if ((rfid.uid.uidByte[0] == UID1[0] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[1] == UID1[1] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[2] == UID1[2] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[3] == UID1[3]) ||
        (rfid.uid.uidByte[0] == UID2[0] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[1] == UID2[1] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[2] == UID2[2] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[3] == UID2[3]) ||
        (rfid.uid.uidByte[0] == UID3[0] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[1] == UID3[1] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[2] == UID3[2] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[3] == UID3[3]) ||
        (rfid.uid.uidByte[0] == UID4[0] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[1] == UID4[1] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[2] == UID4[2] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[3] == UID4[3]) ||
        (rfid.uid.uidByte[0] == UID5[0] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[1] == UID5[1] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[2] == UID5[2] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[3] == UID5[3]) ||
        (rfid.uid.uidByte[0] == UID6[0] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[1] == UID6[1] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[2] == UID6[2] &&
         rfid.uid.uidByte[3] == UID6[3]))
    {
      digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
      delay(15000);
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    }
    rfid.PICC_HaltA();
  }
}
```

Comment: "but the rfid reader stops reading tags".  Does it still respond to opening the door when that happens?

Comment: Yes, rest of "features" works 100% of time - only the reader stops responding :/.

Comment: Your sketch doesn't look very robust, what with long delays in the middle of the main loop. How long does the reader remain unresponsive? Did you make sure the door was closed when you scanned the card? What sort of enclosure did you use around the reader?

Comment: What sort of distance is there between the RFID reader and the Nano?

Comment: 200ms delay at the start is to overall slow everything down, 6000ms one is a timer that starts when door is opened and then closed leaving lights turned on 6s (didn't have it before and problem was still there) and 15000ms one is for when correct tag is present so that light turns on for 15s. Reader stays unresponsive for (i think) forever until the reset. Door is closed 100%, because often when i come back and find it not working i just open the door without it and then light turns on. Enclosure for scanner is a 3D printed case. Relay, arduino and power share space in one separate enclosure

Comment: @timemage about 5-6 meters of cable (used ethernet cable for that)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how to continue with this without turning it into a conversation or doing something what will probably trigger your "throw random ideas" clause, but suffice it to say I think that distance plays a role in the problem.

Comment: @timemage I mean it could be true, but why would it just stop working randomly like that, and how to solve/test it if thats the case (i can't have a shorter cable - this one is made as short as possible)

Comment: I refer you back to my previous comment.